# in parse.com is there a way to duplicate an entire app?

Tags: parse-platform

i don't mind if all the *data* isn't copied, but i do need the entire structure copied.

If there is a way to copy out the data, that would also be fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse released this functionality today :-)

Head to your apps dashboard at https://www.parse.com/apps and click the little cog icon on the app you wish to clone. Then, click on Clone, and you'll be taken through a flow where you can choose which parts of the app you want to clone to a new one.

You can't yet clone Data, or background job schedules according to their [blog announcing the feature](http://blog.parse.com/2014/11/17/attack-of-the-clones/).